# Node + Express how to access to upload folder

Tags: node.js, express

I built an `upload` in my `API` using `multer` that works perfectly.
I'm trying to access at the uploaded files from `Gatsby` but it doesn't work

```
router.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

The files are in `/public/uploads` :

```
http://localhost:5000/public/uploads/364935-2020-08-18.jpg
```

but I can't access them.

I tried different sintaxs:

```
router.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

router.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

router.use(express.static("public"));
```

no one worked

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: try without `public` like `http://localhost:5000/uploads/364935-2020-08-18.jpg`. If you need something out of an static folder / public folder you usually dont need to write `static` or `public` infront of it

Comment: thanks but I tried any combination and it doesn't work

Comment: did you tried to remove the `public` at `router.use("/public"`

Comment: thanks but not. I tried also that

Comment: When you are using this ==> `app.use(express.static("public"));` the access should be `http://localhost:5000/uploads/364935-2020-08-18.jpg` OR if you are using this ==> `app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));` then access it via `http://localhost:5000/public/uploads/364935-2020-08-18.jpg`.

Comment: thanks. but I got it. Wrong expression location...

Answer (score 1):

Trying Node's built-in `path` module:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```